# Rendered nodes overlap in visjs network graph

Tags: vis.js-network, vis.js

I render a graph using visjs. The shape of the nodes are of type dot. Each node is given a custom size using the size attribute.

When the graph is rendered some of the nodes overlap. So the graph looks like in the following picture:

[image: actual graph]

I expected a graph like the this picture is showing:

[image: expected graph]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the physics configuration.

see this [example](http://visjs.org/examples/network/physics/physicsConfiguration.html) of visjs.

GOOD LUCK.

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific compared to the TERMIN's answer, in the physics configuration example you can see (at least for the `barnesHut` solver) that increasing `avoidOverlap` prevents overlapping even when `springConstant` is equal to zero and

```
var options = {
  "physics": {
    "barnesHut": {
      "avoidOverlap": 0.2
    }
  }
}
```

is probably enough (but you may increase the value according to your needs).